# Getting internal server error while using Page.setHtmlContent on google apps script over google sites

Tags: google-apps-script

I have several pages at google sites that each one has some gadgets in their body. 
Now I made a script to edit these pages content but I'm reaching internal server error problem.

To reproduce the problem:

1. Create a page in google sites.
2. Add some gadgets like subpage listing.
3. Try to execute this script:

   ```
   function doGet() {
    var site = SitesApp.getSiteByUrl("Your site URL");
    var page = site.getChildByName("testeiframe");
    Logger.log(page.getHtmlContent());
    page.setHtmlContent(page.getHtmlContent());
   }
   ```

you will get Service error: `SitesApp: Internal Error (line 4, file "Code")`

Log output (Some HTML was generated by added gadgets):

```
[13-05-08 14:56:14:532 BRT] <table class='sites-layout-name-one-column sites-layout-    hbox' cellspacing='0'><tbody><tr><td class='sites-layout-tile sites-tile-name-content-1'>    <div dir='ltr'><table width='100%'>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width='80%'>
<div><br/>
</div>
<br/>
</td>
<td width='20%'>
<div class='sites-embed-align-left-wrapping-off'><div style='width:100%;' class='sites-    embed-border-off sites-embed sites-embed-full-width'><div class='sites-embed-content sites-    embed-type-maestro'><iframe id='maestro_frame_1365991698' scrolling='no' frameborder='0'     height='200' width='100%' title='Apps Script Gadget'     src='https://sites.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwzCf4E-Sh22-IEuo2IDDsQImGCQrWzixBGjWmejA/exec?    mid=ACjPJvEwYP7HUKKoqhvc1HAZh7uLQMQY6F31evULDnTKsS-dpoXuw599A_y-    WPzYCnA4CY6Kg2iPA83GUn5gIt9GEi9jzed6nEotMcU&amp;bc=transparent&amp;f=arial,sans-    serif&amp;tc=%23404041&amp;lc=%23336699'/></div></div></div><img style='display:block;text-    align:left;margin-right:auto;' height='300' width='500' data-    props='align:left;displayAs:TOC;maxDepth:6;' data-type='subpages'     src='http://www.google.com/chart?    chc=sites&amp;cht=d&amp;chdp=sites&amp;chl=%5B%5BPage+listing&apos;%3D20&apos;f%5Cv&apos;a%    5C%3D0&apos;10&apos;%3D499&apos;0&apos;dim&apos;%5Cbox1&apos;b%5CF6F6F6&apos;fC%5CF6F6F6&ap    os;eC%5C0&apos;sk&apos;%5C%5B&apos;%5D&apos;a%5CV%5C%3D12&apos;f%5C%5DV%5Cta%5C%3D10&apos;%    3D0&apos;%3D500&apos;%3D297&apos;dim&apos;%5C%3D10&apos;%3D10&apos;%3D500&apos;%3D297&apos;    vdim&apos;%5Cbox1&apos;b%5Cva%5CF6F6F6&apos;fC%5CC8C8C8&apos;eC%5C&apos;a%5C%5Do%5CLauto&ap    os;f%5C&amp;sig=x5z8H4DplZUYp7X4J5EY798sKFM'/><div class='sites-embed-align-left-    wrapping-off'><div style='width:100%;' class='sites-embed-border-off sites-embed sites-    embed-full-width'><div style='display:none;' class='sites-embed-object-title'>TRT4</div>    <div class='sites-embed-content sites-embed-type-calendar'><iframe scrolling='no'     frameborder='0' height='250' width='100%' title='TRT4'     src='http://www.google.com/calendar/embed?    src=gtbq7elsfvo6j9t42dd139c48k@group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23668CD9&amp;ctz=Etc/GM    T%2B3&amp;showTitle=0&amp;showNav=0&amp;showDate=0&amp;showTabs=0&amp;showCalendars=0&amp;h    l=en' id='1774561823'/></div></div></div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table></div></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: You've got spaces in your log output, are they accidental? `sites-layout-______hbox`, for example.

Comment: Just the copy and paste process. They don't exist in the original output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** Rebuild your page using the editor.

I tried creating a site page using the text you provided in your question, and got exactly the error you report. There's something in there that Sites does not like - I believe it's the attributes in your iframe tags. (I noticed that you had no `</iframe>` tags, btw.)

I have been able to reproduce the page using the Sites editor, taking just the `src` info from your posting, and the result is able to make it through your script without any error.

#### First Gadget

In your original question, the first gadget is an Apps-Script Gadget (based on the `title` in source). Starting with a blank page `testeiframe`, I inserted the gadget, and pasted this value as *the URL of your Apps Script already published as a service*:

```
https://sites.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwzCf4E-Sh22-IEuo2IDDsQImGCQrWzixBGjWmejA/exec?mid=ACjPJvEwYP7HUKKoqhvc1HAZh7uLQMQY6F31evULDnTKsS-dpoXuw599A_y-WPzYCnA4CY6Kg2iPA83GUn5gIt9GEi9jzed6nEotMcU&amp;bc=transparent&amp;f=arial,sans-serif&amp;tc=%23404041&amp;lc=%23336699
```

This leaves out all the offending iframe tags, as mentioned.

**Alternative** - I was also able to insert an iframe directly into the page by using the html editor, and pasting the tags `<iframe src=...></iframe>`. You can follow the instructions [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8llkinnQ2o) to learn how to do that.

#### Second Gadget

Your other gadget is a calendar. I simply used the calendar `src` you provided.

#### Resulting HTML

Using your script, here's the content of the Logger, passed through a [prettyprinter](http://infohound.net/tidy/tidy.pl):

```
<table class='sites-layout-name-one-column sites-layout-hbox' cellspacing='0'>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class='sites-layout-tile sites-tile-name-content-1'>
      <div dir='ltr'>
        <img class='igm' style='display:block;text-align:left;margin-right:auto;'
        height='800' width='500' data-props=
        'height:800;igsrc:http#58//0.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?mid=0&amp;synd=trogedit&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gstatic.com%2Fsites-gadgets%2Fiframe%2Fiframe.xml&amp;up_iframeURL=https%3A%2F%2Fsites.google.com%2Fmacros%2Fs%2FAKfycbwzCf4E-Sh22-IEuo2IDDsQImGCQrWzixBGjWmejA%2Fexec%3Fmid%3DACjPJvGiKo17cYG9syr9gGYY44PEyWdKDJPD4xkYErDWyxsn_6TjyOplXYq0ZCu405D-IKLl41lZVMC648mjzJUxC7EEKTgx7_F8gEE_ZsjP9cFo%26bc%3Dtransparent%26f%3DArial%2C%2BVerdana%2C%2Bsans-serif%26tc%3D%2523444444%26lc%3D%25230033cc&amp;up_scroll=no&amp;w=100%&amp;h=800;mid:0;spec:http#58//www.gstatic.com/sites-gadgets/iframe/iframe.xml;up_iframeURL:https#58//sites.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwzCf4E-Sh22-IEuo2IDDsQImGCQrWzixBGjWmejA/exec?mid=ACjPJvGiKo17cYG9syr9gGYY44PEyWdKDJPD4xkYErDWyxsn_6TjyOplXYq0ZCu405D-IKLl41lZVMC648mjzJUxC7EEKTgx7_F8gEE_ZsjP9cFo&amp;bc=transparent&amp;f=Arial,+Verdana,+sans-serif&amp;tc=%23444444&amp;lc=%230033cc;up_scroll:no;width:100%;'
        data-type='ggs-gadget' data-igsrc=
        'http://0.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?mid=0&amp;synd=trogedit&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gstatic.com%2Fsites-gadgets%2Fiframe%2Fiframe.xml&amp;up_iframeURL=https%3A%2F%2Fsites.google.com%2Fmacros%2Fs%2FAKfycbwzCf4E-Sh22-IEuo2IDDsQImGCQrWzixBGjWmejA%2Fexec%3Fmid%3DACjPJvGiKo17cYG9syr9gGYY44PEyWdKDJPD4xkYErDWyxsn_6TjyOplXYq0ZCu405D-IKLl41lZVMC648mjzJUxC7EEKTgx7_F8gEE_ZsjP9cFo%26bc%3Dtransparent%26f%3DArial%2C%2BVerdana%2C%2Bsans-serif%26tc%3D%2523444444%26lc%3D%25230033cc&amp;up_scroll=no&amp;w=100%&amp;h=800'
        src=
        'http://www.google.com/chart?chc=sites&amp;cht=d&amp;chdp=sites&amp;chl=%5B%5BGoogle+Gadget&#39;%3D20&#39;f%5Cv&#39;a%5C%3D0&#39;10&#39;%3D499&#39;0&#39;dim&#39;%5Cbox1&#39;b%5CF6F6F6&#39;fC%5CF6F6F6&#39;eC%5C0&#39;sk&#39;%5C%5B%22Include+gadget+(iframe)%22&#39;%5D&#39;a%5CV%5C%3D12&#39;f%5C%5DV%5Cta%5C%3D10&#39;%3D0&#39;%3D500&#39;%3D797&#39;dim&#39;%5C%3D10&#39;%3D10&#39;%3D500&#39;%3D797&#39;vdim&#39;%5Cbox1&#39;b%5Cva%5CF6F6F6&#39;fC%5CC8C8C8&#39;eC%5C&#39;a%5C%5Do%5CLauto&#39;f%5C&amp;sig=LIupg-AjxUbah_DqtRj3JecPeDg' />

        <div class='sites-embed-align-left-wrapping-off'>
          <div style='width:100%;' class=
          'sites-embed-border-off sites-embed sites-embed-full-width'>
            <div style='display:none;' class='sites-embed-object-title'>
              Google Calendar
            </div>

            <div class='sites-embed-content sites-embed-type-calendar'>
              <iframe scrolling='no' frameborder='0' height='250' width='100%' title=
              'Google Calendar' src=
              'http://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=gtbq7elsfvo6j9t42dd139c48k@group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23668CD9&amp;ctz=Etc/GMT%252B3&amp;showTitle=1&amp;showNav=0&amp;showDate=0&amp;showTabs=0&amp;showCalendars=0&amp;hl=en'
              id='155565547' name="155565547"></iframe>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

As you pointed out, the gadgets are the source of most of that code. I find it curious that in my case portions of the code were obviously passed through [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), while yours didn't appear to be. (Maybe that point to the actual problem?)

Comment: No,the page isn't null.
I checked it via console.log

Comment: @braraujo - Ok then... your code worked for me, duplicating my existing page, with my own site & page names, so something else is wrong. Did you check whether you received HTML in a string when calling `getHtmlContent()`? You will need to add more info to your question, there just isn't enough to go on right now.

Comment: Updated with the html output